# C# encoding when reading files

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding

I have a file which contains letter `ø`. When I read from it with this code `File.ReadLines(filePath)` I got a question mark instead of it.

And when I add Encoding like this `File.ReadLines(filePath, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))` I get the `ø` character.

But default Encoding is already set to `1252`, property `Encoding.Default.CodePage` returns 1252.

So why do I have to specify Encoding to `1252` while reading, when default one is already set to `1252`?

And one more question, what if file is Unicode, will C# recognize its format or I have to specify Unicode encoding?

Comment: File.ReadLines defaults to utf8 for encoding

Comment: Using a legacy 8-bit codepage encoding, like 1252, is a practice from the previous century.  You simply need to stop doing that, there is no remaining reason today to not use utf-8.  As you found out, File.ReadLines() defaults to Encoding.UTF8.  Delete the file or re-save it with a text editor.  Notepad is already good enough, Encoding combobox on the SaveAs dialog.

Comment: Is UTF-8 default also when writing to file?

Comment: @HansPassant But program receives files in ANSI, I cannot change those files manually to UTF-8.

Comment: Well, of course you can.  After doing that about ten times, you'd consider solving the real problem.  And pick up a telephone instead of asking people that have no way to actually do anything about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that by default the encoding used when reading text files is UTF8.

`Encoding.Default` is not (despite its name) the default encoding used when reading files!

A much better name for `Encoding.Default` would have been `Encoding.UsingCurrentCodePage`, in my opinion. ;)

Also note that rather than using `File.ReadLines(filePath, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))` you could use `File.ReadLines(filePath, Encoding.Default)`.

You would do that if your code is trying to read files that have been created in a different code page than 1252, and that code page is the current code page for the system on which the code is running.

The only reason you should be using code pages is if you are reading or writing legacy files.

Comment: Is UTF-8 also default when writing to file?

Comment: @Aleksa Yep. It's the standard for files nowadays.

Comment: after loads of testing , I found following code works better rather than "Encoding.Default"

 var csvContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(import.File.LocalPath, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"));

Comment: Amazing. Tried every value except 'Default' because why would I try that...!